# Indirect Recursion in Grammar

Tags: parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, grammar

I'm trying to remove the indirect recursion from the following grammar:

```
F -> P X
X -> R C
R -> C R | I R | epsilon
```

All capital letters are non-terminals, I have just left off the productions as they aren't important.

Following this through, you can see that I will get something that looks like F -> P (C | I)* C which is causing issues for my recursive descent parser.

Any valid expression must end in C but this final C is always consumed by repeatedly using the R production leaving no tokens left for final C of the X -> R C production.

Take the following expression of tokens as an example: "P C I C"

- We use the F -> P X production to remove the first P leaving "C I C"
- Then X -> R C -> C R C so we can consume the C leaving "I C"
- Then R C -> I R C so we can consume the I leaving "C"

Now we hit the problem. A recursive decent parser will simply choose to continue expanding the R like so:

- R C -> C R C so we consume the final character C leaving no remaining tokens!

At this point, my program will error despite the valid input because the final R C -> C (using the epsilon production) and there is no remaining C to match!

I think all I need to do is cleverly rearrange the grammar in some way to remove this ambiguity. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful If you use a "recursive" descent parser for grammars _not_ involving recursion, it's not a recursive descent parser...

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful It's logically true. If the grammar has no recursion, there's no need for recursion to happen while parsing. The method to parse R in OP's grammar necessarily recurses because the grammar recurses.

Comment: @davmac - Well, so true. It has been a long while having taken the class of compiler design(more than a year ago), YOU're right. I agree, @OP - It should be the word `descent`, not decent.

Comment: Is the input followed by a terminator (end-of-file or the like) which you can use (by means of lookahead) to choose the correct production rule for `R`?

Comment: Is FIRST(I) in FOLLOW(F)?

Comment: So, the grammar I've taken an example from is [here](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-12/msg00699.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite `P (C | I)* C` as `P I* C+ (I+ C+)*`, which is straightforward to implement as a recursive-descent parser. If you write it out as a right-recursive BNF grammar, you'll end up with incorrect associativity, but normally you would write the recursive descent parser with loops, using the extended BNF as above. [Note 1]

In effect, once you parse the `P`, you end up with something like this:

```
do {
  while (try_parse(I)) {}
  parse(C);
  while (try_parse(C)) {}
} while (try_parse(I));
```

---

#### Notes

1. Or, at least, I would, if I wrote recursive descent parsers any more. This is much more straight-forward as a left-recursive grammar and it's LALR(1) so you can generate a parser with bison.